# Javascript callback function executed 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

users can sign in to my system using google sign in so when use pressing google sign in button his account will be create in mysql database 
my problem is every users account created two time when user trying to sign in by google 
in other words function of create account executed two time for every user 
here is my  html code

```
<a id="gp_login" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:googleAuth()">Login using Google</a>
```

this is javascript code

```js
function gPOnLoad(){
     // G+ api loaded
     document.getElementById('gp_login').style.display = 'block';
}
function googleAuth() {
    gapi.auth.signIn({
        callback: 'gPSignInCallback',
        clientid: '636950137786-j3siaftgshtf9iamovisf603pplv7jf1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
        requestvisibleactions: "http://schema.org/AddAction",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read"
    })
}

function gPSignInCallback(e) {
    if (e["status"]["signed_in"]) {
        gapi.client.load("plus", "v1", function() {
            if (e["access_token"]) {
                getProfile()
            } else if (e["error"]) {alert(e['error'])
                console.log("There was an error: " + e["error"])
            }
        })
    } else {alert(e["error"]);
        console.log("Sign-in state: " + e["error"])
    }
}

function getProfile() {
    //var e = googleData.getBasicProfile();

   var e = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
       userId: "me"
    });
    e.execute(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {alert(e.message)
            console.log(e.message);
            return
        } else if (e.id) {var msgs=JSON.stringify(e);
           alert(e.displayName);
   update_user_data(e);



           // save profile data
        }
    })
}(function() {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.type = "text/javascript";
    e.async = true;
    e.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=gPOnLoad";
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
})()

function update_user_data(response) 
{
    // var dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
var email=response.emails[0]['value'];
var  displayName=response.displayName;

//ar 

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            data: {email:email,displayName:displayName},
            url: 'Save.php?id=check_user',
            success: function(msg) {


        var array = msg.split(',');
            var email =array[0];alert(email);
    var password = array[1];alert(password);
    $('#username').val(email);$('#password').val(password);
document.getElementById("modal4c").click();
            },
               error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {//alert(JSON.stringify(msg));

            }
      });
}
```

update_user_data() function is to insert account into mysql database but this function is called twice per user.

Comment: can you create some fiddle removing all google code only functions 
so it would be easy to try, what the problem is

Comment: the problem is  the function update_user_data execute tow times for one user which mean every user will has tow account in to database

Comment: Check for Double click

Comment: I checked there is only one click

Comment: Add console.log before `e.execute` and inside `e.execute`

Comment: Insert breakpoints in your code to figure out why is it being called twice. Also... there is no reason why you want to use inline JS, especially when you have jQuery loaded which makes binding event handlers extremely easy.

Comment: can you explain more clearly about why using inline js ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you function runs twice but,
one way to ensure a function runs only once would be make some global flag like this

```
runOnce = false;

function gPSignInCallback(e) {
  if(runOnce) return;
  runOnce = true;
  // ... rest of the function
}
```

If you want to avoid global vars you could return a closure like this

```
 function update_user_data(e){
   var runOnce = false
   return function(){
     if(runOnce) return;
     runOnce = true;
     // ... rest of the function
   }
 }
```

And call it like this `update_user_data()(e)`